# grab multiple instances of ID within an application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the below that is setup and working properly.

```
 require(['models/profile'], function (SectionModel) {
            var sectionModel = new SectionModel({id: merchantId, silent: true});
            sectionModel.fetch({
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#merchant-name').html(data.attributes.merchantName);
                }
            });
        });
```

But it will only work in one instance. I am wondering how to correctly edit the above code to allow multiple instances.

```
<h3 id="merchant-name"></h3>
```

The content is generated within 'Save' function.

```
        merchantName:$('#merchantName').val(),
```

Comment: It's bad practice to have multiple instances of an ID. IDs are supposed to be *unique*. Use class instead.

Comment: id's should be unique on the models as well, identical id's will be merged by Backbone.js's Collection.set() & reset(). To clarify, class should be used on the html.

Comment: I believe convention is to access model properties with the get method instead of using attributes: data.get(merchant Name'). I know it's unrelated to your question but I thought I would point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is set up the rest of the components for the Backbone application. The beauty of Backbone.js is it's ability to separate collections, models and views so your logic stays in a proper place.

You'll want to use an AJAX call to retrieve your models from the server using a Collection. Then, use the collection's reset function.

Here's an example of how you might fetch a collection of models from the server.

```
var MyCollectionType = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    getModelsFromServer:function()
   {
       var me = this;
       function ajaxSuccess(data,  textStatus, jqXHR)
       {
       me.reset(data);
       }

       $.ajax(/* Insert the ajax params here*/);

   } 

});

var collectionInstance = new MyCollectionType({
    model:YourModelTypeHere
    });

collectionInstance.getModelsFromServer();
```

Then, to render each one, you'll want to make a View for each model, and a Collection View. There are a lot of resources though on learning basic Backbone.js and I feel that you might benefit from looking at a few of those.

Keep in mind that Backbone collections will by default merge models with the same id. 'id' usually references a model in the backend of an application, so make sure each id is actually what you want it to be. I work with an application that has a non-Restfull back end, and so ID's are never transferred to the front end.

There are some excellent resources available to begin starting with Backbone.js.

https://www.codeschool.com/courses/anatomy-of-backbonejs
(This is a free course up to a point, and a great starter.)

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-started-with-backbone-js/

http://javascriptissexy.com/learn-backbone-js-completely/